# Is there a Python library or method for accessing the Salesforce Metadata API?

Tags: python, web-services, salesforce, force.com

I need to periodically query a salesforce instance for information that is seemingly only available in the metadata API (login IP ranges per profile). While I know I can use Ant or the Force.com migration tool, I'd like to be able to query it more like I can with the standard Soap API using the wonderful python libraries that exist already.
It seems like for now I'll have to pull down xml files for each profile and programmatically open and parse through the xml for each one as I don't think you can directly query data from the Metadata API (just retrieve or deploy). 
Any advice on how to get this data another way? I'm not opposed to screen scraping with Selenium or some other method but don't think that would work since the number of profiles could change or would be different if testing multiple instances with the same code.
Thank you!

Comment: [simple-salesforce](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simple-salesforce/0.65.1) allows you to run queries and returns results in an ordereddictionary. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

Try [beatbox 20.0 .](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/beatbox/20.0)
A Python library for querying/updating Saleforce.com data via SOAP API.

Comment: Thanks Nilesh - I am using beatbox for some queries, but unfortunately the login IP ranges set in each profile is not available in the SOAP API :(